# How to know contents of column names in GRASS?

Tags: vector, grass-gis

I am using GRASS to extract a specific area from a vector map. Here is the script that I am running:

`v.extract PHL_map out=makati where="AREA_NAME = 'Makati"`

The problem is, I don't know what are the values of the column names. I can only view the column names but I can't view the values under the column names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking just for column values, you probably want [v.db.select](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/v.db.select.html) to get back the column values. Just doing `v.db.select map=vector_layer` will return a pipe separated list of the attribute table. You can also use `columns=` to select particular columns, and `where=` to provide a where clause.

Also useful is `db.describe table=vector_layer` which will return a list of columns along with their relevant metadata and attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I used:
v.extract PHL_adm1 where="NAME_1='Surigao del Sur'" out=surigao

but when I loaded the vector layers, the surigao map did not load. 

This is displayed in the command output:
Writing attributes...
DBMI-DBF driver error:
Unable to create table <angat.surigao>
Unable to copy table
v.extract complete.
(Sat Jan 29 15:23:22 2011) Command finished (0 sec)  

I don't know why the surigao map did not load..

Comment: Note that a dot in a name is not SQL compliant. Please change "angat.surigao" to, for example to "angat_surigao"